# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, exception

I have written this code to fetch data from jTable and show it on the console, but I am facing an error (Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException). Please tell me what condition I should use to get rid of it. I want to check if the next entry of jTable is empty then come out of loop.
    import java.io.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;

```
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JSeparator;


public class SaleInvoice extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form SaleInvoice
     */
public SaleInvoice() {
    setExtendedState(javax.swing.JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 
    initComponents();


}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jTextField4 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    label1 = new java.awt.Label();
    label2 = new java.awt.Label();
    label3 = new java.awt.Label();
    label4 = new java.awt.Label();
    jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
    jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jTextField5 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField6 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField7 = new javax.swing.JTextField();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Sale Invoice");
    setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    setAutoRequestFocus(false);
    setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
    setResizable(false);

    jLabel1.setText("Customer Name");

    jLabel2.setText("Contact #");

    jTextField2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jTextField2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel3.setText("Bill No");

    jLabel4.setText("Date");

    jTextField4.setDisabledTextColor(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    jTextField4.setSelectionColor(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));

    label1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Bodoni MT Black", 3, 48)); // NOI18N
    label1.setText("Pak Madina Traders");

    label2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 3, 18)); // NOI18N
    label2.setText("Deals In All Kind Of New And Used Laptop ");

    label3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 3, 16)); // NOI18N
    label3.setText("59A 4th Floor Hafez Center Main Boulevard Gulberg III Lahore");

    label4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 3, 16)); // NOI18N
    label4.setText("Tel: 042 35717770 Email:pakmadinalaptop@hotmail.com");

    jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Debit", "Credit" }));

    jLabel5.setText("Bill Type");

    jTable1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));
    jTable1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Verdana", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {
            {null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null}
        },
        new String [] {
            "Sr #", "Product Description", "Lot #", "Qty", "Rate", "Amount"
        }
    ) {
        Class[] types = new Class [] {
            java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.Integer.class
        };

        public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return types [columnIndex];
        }
    });
    jTable1.setAutoResizeMode(javax.swing.JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
    jTable1.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
    jTable1.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.TEXT_CURSOR));
    jTable1.setGridColor(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
    jTable1.setName(""); // NOI18N
    jTable1.setRowHeight(30);
    jTable1.setSelectionBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    jTable1.setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    jTable1.setSurrendersFocusOnKeystroke(true);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);
    jTable1.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    if (jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumnCount() > 0) {
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setResizable(false);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(60);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(400);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setResizable(false);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setResizable(false);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(80);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setResizable(false);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(150);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setPreferredWidth(170);
    }

    jButton1.setText("Submit");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
          // jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);


    if(evt.getSource()==jButton1)
    {
        int col=0,row=0;
        String SR,PD,LOT,QTY,RATE,AMT;//check=jTable1.getValueAt(row, col).toString();

        int count=jTable1.getRowCount();
        for(row = 0 ;(!(jTable1.getValueAt(row, col).toString()).equals(null)); row++)
        {
            SR=new String(jTable1.getValueAt(row, col).toString());
            col++;
            PD=new String(jTable1.getValueAt(row, col).toString());
            col++;
            LOT=new String(jTable1.getValueAt(row, col).toString());
            col++;
            QTY=new String(jTable1.getValueAt(row, col).toString());
            col++;
            RATE=new String(jTable1.getValueAt(row, col).toString());
            col++;
            AMT=new String(jTable1.getValueAt(row, col).toString());

            System.out.println("Sr#                   : " + SR);
            System.out.println("Product Discription   : " + PD);
            System.out.println("Lot#                  : " + LOT);
            System.out.println("Quantity              : " + QTY);
            System.out.println("Rate                  : " + RATE);
            System.out.println("Amount                : " + AMT);
            col=0;
            //check=jTable1.getValueAt(row, col).toString();


        }



    }



    }
    });

    jButton3.setText("Back ");
    jButton3.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));

    jLabel6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 3, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel6.setText("Total");

    jLabel7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 3, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel7.setText("ADVANCE");

    jLabel8.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 3, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel8.setText("BALANCE");

    jTextField5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 3, 14)); // NOI18N

    jTextField6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    jTextField6.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.TEXT_CURSOR));

    jTextField7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 1, 14)); // NOI18N

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(54, 54, 54)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 92, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 292, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 75, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(13, 13, 13)
                    .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 292, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 953, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 152, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(jLabel7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 79, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(jLabel8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 79, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(jLabel6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 79, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                .addComponent(jTextField7)
                                .addComponent(jTextField6)
                                .addComponent(jTextField5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 155, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                        .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 152, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(110, 110, 110)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 292, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(label1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 643, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(56, 56, 56)
                            .addComponent(label2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addComponent(label3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 605, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(21, 21, 21)
                            .addComponent(label4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 479, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 75, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 292, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(55, 55, 55)
                            .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 57, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(81, 81, 81)
                            .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 214, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))))
            .addContainerGap(80, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(label1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 59, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(19, 19, 19)
            .addComponent(label2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 36, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(10, 10, 10)
            .addComponent(label3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(19, 19, 19)
            .addComponent(label4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 29, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 29, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 29, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 29, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 29, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 29, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 29, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 29, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 29, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 29, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(1, 1, 1)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 29, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jTextField5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 29, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(28, 28, 28)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addComponent(jLabel7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jTextField7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 29, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(27, 27, 27)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addComponent(jLabel8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jTextField6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 29, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 38, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(60, 60, 60)
                    .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 38, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 347, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(90, 90, 90))
    );

    setBounds(0, 0, 1373, 773);
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jTextField2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                           

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Metal".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SaleInvoice.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SaleInvoice.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SaleInvoice.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SaleInvoice.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new SaleInvoice().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField4;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField5;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField6;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField7;
private java.awt.Label label1;
private java.awt.Label label2;
private java.awt.Label label3;
private java.awt.Label label4;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Please suggest me some solution i will be very thankful to you.

Comment: Post the full stacktrace or at least mark the line the error is happening in. Nobody here will read through all this code to find a line that might cause an NPE.

Comment: the line is this condition
 for(row = 0 ;(!(jTable1.getValueAt(row, col).toString()).equals(null)); row++)
if the next entry is null it will generate error.
i have initialized my jTable of 20 rows and 6 columns with null at each entry.

Comment: You should **never** check for null using the `.equals(...)` method. You would always use `==` or `!=`. Else you risk NPE's since you'd be calling a method `.equals()`, on a null variable.

Comment: i have done this by using == but still not working still exception is occurring.i have done it as
for(row = 0 ;!((jTable1.getValueAt(row, col).toString())==(null)); row++)

Answer (score 1):

Do a null check before the condition

```
if (jTable1.getValueAt(row, col) != null) {
    final String string = jTable1.getValueAt(row, col).toString();
    for(row = 0; row != null; row++) {
         //your code
    }
}
```